# Update 1 column from sql backup file

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table `srSignals`, in a database called `signals` that looks like so:

```
animal      inserttime              id
dog         1970-00-00 00:00:00     3042
cat         1970-00-00 00:00:00     3041
monkey      1970-00-00 00:00:00     3040
hamster     1970-00-00 00:00:00     6
```

All of my `inserttime` values got reset to 1970 on accident. Luckily I have a backup of the database `signals` with the correct `inserttime` values (and corresponding `id` values). The backup file is called `signals.sql.gz` (with `signals.sql` inside the gz compression, obviously).

My question is this: using phpMyAdmin, how can I `update` the column `inserttime` where the `id` of the existing table = the `id` of the backup file. Note that I do NOT want to completely restore the table as other stuff has been added to the database in the interim.

I'm not sure the best way to get about this - restore functionality of phpMyAdmin? Some fancy update / load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restore the backup to a different database and then do an update:

```
UPDATE database1.table, database2.table
SET database1.table.field = database2.table.field
WHERE database1.table.idfield = database2.table.idfield
```

Comment: Jim's answer is better (though it doesn't have to be a different database, just a different table name).

Comment: getting error '#1054 column database2.table.idfield does not exist in where clause' though I can assure you the column does exist. Do I need to use a join statement here to make this work?

Comment: I ended up going with this solution though a slightly different way: I extracted just the backup table I needed from the .sql file, created a new table and imported the backup table (same database), and then ran an UPDATE command to solve my problem: UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON `table1`.`id` = `table2 `.`id` SET `table1`.`inserttime` = `table2 `.`inserttime`