# Mysql retrieve data from back up sql

Tags: mysql, backup

We back up our mysql database every day around 2.00am.
yesterday, we did an accidental update to a column and that's affected the entire database instead of just one record.

Question :
  Is it possible to get a column value from backup and use that to update the live database ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update 1 column from sql backup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485239/update-1-column-from-sql-backup-file)

Comment: That helped.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to restore the backup to a separate database, query the column in question including the record's primary key.

Then transform the result of that's query into an update statement that you can execute on the live database.

I would advise to try this on a test environment first.